# ¿Como pasar valores de react a js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables, react-native, variables-globales

Tengo un arreglo o un valor en react(Soy nuevo en react).
Entiendo mas javascript y se como manejar valores, variables arreglos en js, pero estoy empezando en react y es un mundo diferente.
Me han dicho que con una variable global pero no se mucho de react como pasar un valor de react a js.
PD: Lo busco en google y no sale nada.
 `No he intentado código porque desconozco de mandar valores de react a js`
Me refiero a que tengo:
el archivo app.js con  var reciboreact;
y el archivo de react react.js o jsx  con let valor = 5;

como mando el valor del archivo de react al archivo de js

Comment: No entiendo bien la pregunta, como que de React a JS? Podrías ser más específico? Puedo entender que lo que quieres es usar correctamente el JSX.

Comment: Especifica tu pregunta por favor. Agrega el código que tienes y lo que quieres hacer. React es javascript, solo que incluye una especie de azúcar sintáctico para embeber html en tu código. Por otro lado, limita las etiquetas a tu problema específico ¿Es react o react-native? No es lo mismo.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: React está construido con JavaScript así que no hay ninguna manera de mandar los datos de uno a otro porque no hay diferenciación. Cuando se utiliza React al final se utiliza integramente JavaScript o TypeScript dependiendo del proyecto.
La pregunta no es como pasar valores entre ellos sino como tratar los datos que ya tengo en React. Modifica tu pregunta diciendo qué es lo que quieres hacer y qué es lo que tienes para que podamos entender un poco mejor y poder ayudarte

Comment: Es estilo libre -lsanchezo, me refiero a que tengo un valor de react y quiero mandarlo a js, soy nuevo y he buscado y no he encontrado algo para hacer eso me surgio la duda.

Comment: – David Fernández Flores Gracias a ti y  lsanchezo por tomarse la molestia de contestar mi duda, solo quiero pasar un valor de una variable o constante de react a js, de la manera mas simple es estilo libre, no quiero entrar en detalles para no complicar mas, solo quiero saber si existe una forma de mandar valores de react a js solo eso.
Me refiero a que tengo:
el archivo app.js con  var reciboreact;
y el archivo de react react.js o jsx, como mando el valor del archivo de react al archivo de js

Comment: Usa state. Para actualizar el valor debes entender que no se lo hace directamente como en `js`, debes actualizar el estado de tu variable(modificar el state).

Comment: no me queda muy clara la pregunta, lo que entiendo es lo siguiente. Entiendo que tiene es archivo app.js (principal) donde tienes una variable, a la que te gustaría asignar un valor de una variable que está en otro archivo. Si este es el caso, tal vez te pueda servir de guía esta respuesta. Para realizar esto podrías exportar la variable en el archivo que comentas, e importarlo en el app.js. Esto funciona si pero no es lo ideal, es decir hay casos en los que esto puede ser necesario, pero no es lo normal realizar el intercambio de esta manera (ojo que es en base a lo que entendí que intentas h